# Is there any evidence to suggest that exercise reduces the side effects of caffeine?

Tags: human-biology, neuroscience, brain, metabolism, bioenergetics

I heard a friend say:

> I'm not drinking coffee this week. My body can only process the caffeine if I run at least 15km a week.

I found this claim fascinating - that exercise temporarily increases the caffeine tolerance of the body.

Caffeine [side effects](http://www.webmd.com/vitamins-supplements/ingredientmono-979-caffeine.aspx?activeingredientid=979) [include](http://www.caffeineinformer.com/harmful-effects-of-caffeine):

- Sleeplessness
- Additional grogginess when waking up
- Withdrawal headaches
- Decreased empathy
- A decreased ability to listen to orally spoken detail
- A decreased ability to calmly think

My question is: **Is there any evidence to suggest that exercise reduces the side effects of caffeine?**

Comment: What side effects?

Comment: There are many things that they could mean, some of which even make sense. Exercise could help lower blood sugar, and so help consume the increased glycogen caffeine triggers. It could also help if the person is getting jittery from increased respiration. Finally, increasing metabolism will flush the stuff faster. Beyond those, I can't think of anything off the top of my head.

Comment: Can you please reference where you got your side effects list from.

Comment: Hi @AMR - I've referenced it - does that help you out?